# How to retrieve the data back from ifstream

Tags: c++, ifstream

I am using the following code to save the array data into file

```
ofstream out;
out.open("Database.txt", ios::trunc);

for(int t=0; t<Data_Counter; t++)
{
     out << t <<endl;
     out << Data[t].getName() << endl;
     out << Data[t].getID() << endl;
}
out.close();
```

now I want to retrieve the data back in the same array positions. What do I need to add in the following code to make it work:

```
ifstream in;
in.open("\Database.txt", ios::in);

// what logic to use
in.close();
```

Comment: Couldn't the documentation tell you what to do?

Comment: At least have a bash at some code? Just doing the reverse of the output code would be a good starter.

Comment: If this is too hard, solve a simpler problem first. Write "hello world" to a file and retrieve it.

Comment: ohh Come on people .... please answer or atleast tell me what to do ...  I need it urgently :P

Comment: The way you are saving your output is not helpful. If you can you should save a count of the number of items in your database first. I guess that's the part you are struggling with, you don't know how many items you have to read.

Comment: @user2625486 People are more inclined to help if you at least explain what you are struggling with. I've *guessed* that the issue is that you're confused because you don't know how many items you have to read, but that's only a guess.

Comment: @user2625486 Another issue could be that you don't know how to stop reading when you reach the end of the file. Another issue could be that you don't know how to add items to the `Data` array/vector (which is it?). Really you should help us help yourself.

Comment: @john he has some Data_Counter. I guess, that can give him the number of times he has to read.

Comment: @Zeeshan Maybe but maybe not, it's another thing we're just guessing about at the moment.

Comment: @john My problem is that I want to make a for loop which should run at the end of file and then stops.

Comment: @user2625486 That's easy enough to do, although you should use a while loop, not a for loop. For loops are generally only used when you know in advance how many times you need to go round the loop. That's not the case here. I'll write up an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To read to the end of your file use some code like this

```
int index;
string name, id;
while (in >> index >> name >> id)
{
    // do something with index, name and id
}
```

This works because `in >> ...` is only true when the read was successful. So when you get to the end of the file `in >> ...` will be false and the while loop will terminate.

I am assuming that there's no whitespace in your names and ids. If that's not the case then you have a slightly more difficult problem.

Another way is to take advantage of the fact that your input is separated by newlines and do this

```
string index, name, id;
while (getline(in, index) && getline(in, name) && getline(in, id))
{
    // do something with index, name and id
}
```

The advantage of this version is that it will work if you have spaces in your name. The disadvantage is that `getline` only works with strings. So you have to convert `index` from a string to an integer.

Comment: thx, but one more thing suppose that data saved in the file is like this, first name, then in new line its the ID, and it goes on like this , how can I save that data back into my Data[x].name and Data[x].ID.

Comment: @user2625486 The code above doesn't care about newlines. It skips all whitespace so it will work even if you have a newline between the name and the id. But see my editted answer.

Comment: @user2625486 To say how to store the data into `Data` I would first have to know what `Data` is. Is it a static array, a dynamically allocated array, a vector? Your question doesn't make this clear.

Comment: its static array "UserDetails Data[100];"

Comment: @user2625486 Then it's very simple, something like `Data_Counter = 0; while (...) { Data[Data_Counter].name = name; Data[Data_Counter].id = id; ++Data_Counter; }`. Basically just use `Data_Counter` (or any other variable you like) to keep track of how many items you've added to your array so far. Each time you add one item to `Data` increment `Data_Counter`.

Answer (score 1):

Just to get you on track,

```
int xyz;
in>>xyz;
```

This will read the integer at your first line, which you stored as "t". Now try to loop and read strings, line by line, and store them. Good luck.